# How can I catch an outside cat in order to give it medical treatment?

Tags: cats, injury, feral

There is a wild cat which comes to our house thrice a day to eat food. Somebody tied a rope on her back portion. Now as the cat is growing up there is a wound on her back. Please look at her back in the pictures and suggest me a best solution to cure her.

[image: look at the rope on her back portion]

[image: look at the wound increasing day by day due to rope]

Comment: Has the rope been removed? If so can estimate how long the rope has been gone?

Comment: No the rope is still tied. and we are unable to catch the cat. it jumps and goes wild

Comment: What about going to the vet and explaining the situation? May be they can lend you a trap or a may be they can give you a sedative you can feed the cat and after that you can follow him around and then take the rope off? This is quite an urgen situation, the cat has to be in pain and this will only get worse. You need to act asap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your location, you may have the option of a travelling vet that would be willing to come to you. If so then the tricky part is actually getting the cat into a controlled environment.

If you have a garage or are ok with having the cat in your home (assuming you do not have other pets that would complicate matters), then try and win the cat's trust. Go out and simply speak to it, try to give it food, etc. I have a cat that used to be a stray that all I did was go out with food which I put down and sat next to. It would come and eat and I would just talk to it. A couple of day's later he was sitting in my lap. Once you have the cat's trust you can have him follow you to the safe area (again garage, etc.) so that you can coordinate having the vet visit.

Be careful with trying to rush things and picking up the cat. He could hurt you if just trying to get away, and poor thing may not be exactly healthy.

I hope you are able to help it. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You really do need to trap her and get her to a vet. Humane traps of several types can be purchased, or you could try building one of the designs used by the organizations which trap and neuter feral cats in various cities.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to lure the cat into a shed, garage, or house, as keshlam suggests.

Or see if you can borrow a humane trap from someone. Try animal shelters, humane associations, vets, even pest control companies or hunters.

Alternatively, you can build a simple humane trap yourself. I did a web search for "build humane trap" and found many links. Here's one, but you may be able to find others that need minimal construction and only require materials you have on hand.
http://www.instructables.com/id/Building-a-low-pressure-humane-animal-trap/