# How to trap an untrappable pest tom cat

Tags: cats, feral

I have three stray tom cats trying to claim territory at my house (indoors & outdoors). I have 2 neutered Burmese females who are a little nervous of their presence.

How can I attract them or one of them at least into a trap. They seem to be extra cautious of it.

Comment: Just curious, are you trying to relocate this tom cat?

Comment: Related [Why are cats released as part of “spay and release” programs?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1699/why-are-cats-released-as-part-of-spay-and-release-programs)

Comment: There are some suggestions in the question [How can I catch an outside cat in order to give it medical treatment?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/8141/how-can-i-catch-an-outside-cat-in-order-to-give-it-medical-treatment) can you expand your question to include methods you have tried but have not worked?

Comment: I just want to get rid of these pest cats!! to RSPCA, YAPS, Council, or anyone who wants them;  I have tried the big trap - tuna, prawns, bikkies, cat food - to no avail!!!!  Council says they will see if they are chipped but I have to trap them first!!

Answer (score 2):

Using a drop trap might help. They are kind of big and you can bait them for days before trying to trap. Get them used to eating under the drop trap, then trap them a couple weeks later.